Quarkus file upload to AWS S3 insufficient data written
I am trying to develop a functionality where user uploads a file through a form and sends it on API. API (Quarkus) will save this file in AWS S3 bucket. Unfortunately, I am unable to implement a logic to upload a file to S3.
Dependencies used:
implementation 'io.quarkiverse.amazonservices:quarkus-amazon-s3:2.16.0'
implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:url-connection-client:2.26.7'

Resource:
@POST
@Path("upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response saveReportAttachment(MultipartBody data) {
        PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder().bucket("bucket-name").key(data.fileName).build();
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.fromInputStream(data.file, IoUtils.toByteArray(data.file).length);
        PutObjectResponse response = s3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest, requestBody);
        return Response.ok().build();
    }

MultipartBody:
public class MultipartBody {

    @FormParam("file")
    @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public InputStream file;

    @FormParam("fileName")
    @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String fileName;
}

application properties:
amazonProperties.endpointUrl=https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
amazonProperties.accessKey=XXX
amazonProperties.secretKey=XXXXXX
amazonProperties.bucketName=bucket-name

Error: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: insufficient data written
Seems like I am missing something related to file data, but I have no idea, what to do. Maybe I should try different approach with the MultipartBody dto? When I try to save the file to local directory, it works.
